# jQuery: undo things when history:back?

Tags: jquery

i know this question might be too easy, but i have no idea how to solve this.

when submitting a form i'll fadeIn a Loading-Image. When submitting the form was a success the page redirects blabla...

Now when I hit the BACK Button in my browser and i visit the previous page with the form the Loading-Image is still shown.

How can i make that hide again?

regards

Comment: Did you try just hiding it in a `document.ready` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're sending this via ajax since you get a loading screen. Just attach the image to hide on success.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/form.html',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.loadingImage').fadeIn("slow");
  }
  success: function() {
    $('.loadingImage').fadeOut("fast");
  };
});
```

Comment: no i'm not using ajax, I'm just using … $("form").submit(function() { $('#spinner').fadeIn('slow');

Comment: i thought of using the unload() method, but i'm not really unloading a page. if the form is submitted i'm just showing running through an include!

Answer (score 1):

and what if you do a [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which solves the duplicate form submitting as well?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something as simple as this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loadingImage').hide();
});
```

Just making sure that when your page is loaded your image is hidde.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually submitting the form, then yes, you're unloading the page.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).unload(function(){
    $('.loadingImage').hide();
  });
});
```

That'll hide it before you actually leave the page.